# Can't get mod_rewrite to work when only having to rewrite certain urls

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following Rules setup in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^detail.php / [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^tempate.php / [R=301,NC,L]
```

What these do is perform a 301 redirect when detail.php and template.php is called, although this works this is not working when I enter `mydomain.co.za/detail.php?product_id=2432&category=700` then it redirects the website to `mydomain.co.za/?product_id=2432&category=700`

I need any url where the filename is `detail.php` or `template.php` with any amount of parameters in the query string to redirect to the home page

I tried `RewriteRule ^detail.php?(.*) / [R=301,NC,L]` and this also not working. Any help or guide will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your 2 RewriteRule lines with this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:detail|template)\.php$ /? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Note that question mark after `/`, that is a special mod_rewrite syntax to strip out any existing query string from original URI.

Also remember that RewriteRule only matches URI without query string therefore your attempt of `^detail.php?(.*) / [R=301,NC,L]` won't work as you expected.

Comment: Fantastic, makes now perfect sense. Implemented and tested and it works perfectly as expected